# Creating a DataTable From a Linq Query in my C# Windows form

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Creating a DataTable From a Linq Query
I use Ling to show my data on dataGridview and I have linq search funtion to search poeple. It's workin fine but not as Datatable do. I have to write the hole name before my serch function shoe me the name. I want to create Creat a DataTable From a Linq Query but I donät know how to do it. 
Here is my code:

```
public void SerachdataEmp(string name)
{
    db = new EmployeeEntity();
    var result = (from u in db.Employee
    join d in db.Department on u.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId 
    where u.FirstName == name
    select new
    {                            
       FirstName = u.FirstName,
       LastName = u.LastNameName,
       DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName 
    }      
}).Tolist();
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

I tried like this

```
(from u in db.Employee.AsEnumerable()
 join d in db.Department.AsEnumerable() on u.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId 
 where u.FirstName == searchEmployee

but then I don't know how to do. Thank you in advance!
```

Comment: I believe `DataGridView` should support an anonymous type - what happens when you use your code?

Comment: *not as Datatable do* What do you mean? You already have everything available to perform all kinds of searches. What does a DataTable add to that?

Comment: @Gert Arnold , thank you for your response. If I have a name with begining A or B then it shows me only if I write the hole name, it's not filtering in the begining.But if is Datatable with SqlConnecting , then I just need to input for example for "Johannes" I just need to input J then shows me all names who beginns with J before I put "Johannes". But right now I have to put "Johannes" to show me all pople who's name is Johannes. Sorry if I confuse you..;)

Comment: Look, a DataTable doesn't *do* anything. If you use it for selection queries it's the query that does the job. You just have a different query that contains something like `StartsWith`. You can do exactly the same thing in LINQ (`u.FirstName.StartWith...`)

Comment: @GertArnold  Do you mean like this   u.FirstName.StartsWith == username?

Answer (score 0):

instead use query.ToList();

use

```
 query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: That only works if `query` returns `IEnumerable<DataRow>` or a subclass of `DataRow`.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for respons, but How can I formulate then IEnumerable<DataRow>?

Comment: @Paulo , thank you for responce, but how should be look like my code then?

Comment: @HelenTekie I don't recommend that.

Comment: @NetMage Thank. It's too complicated for me So I prefer to use SqlConnection. But my Project is buld by ADO:NET ENTITY DATA MODEL. So It's ok t oimplement two different Connection strings, One ADO.NET Entity and the other one SqlConnection System.Data.SqlClient ? Becouse When to use DataTable it work bete rwith SqlConnection. But is tha tnorma lto use two different Connections in one single Project?

Comment: @HelenTekie I have no idea what you are trying to say, and I think you commented on the wrong answer.

Comment: @NetMage that code you wrote above is complicated for me to uderstand (that code you do not recomend) so even if you recomended and then I would not understand it. I'am not so good on programing. My question was, Right now I have ADO.NET Entity Connection in my Project. But it is OK to use multiple Connections like SqlConnection System.Data.SqlClient , beside ADO.NET Entity Model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, and I don't believe your search issue is with not using a `DataTable`, but using these extensions you can convert your query answer into a `DataTable` - just put `ToDataTable()` in place of `ToList()`.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    // ***
    // *** IEnumerable<> Extensions
    // ***
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rows) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        if (rows.Any()) {
            var rowType = typeof(T);
            var memberInfos = rowType.GetPropertiesOrFields();
            foreach (var info in memberInfos)
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.GetMemberType()));

            foreach (var r in rows)
                dt.Rows.Add(memberInfos.Select(i => i.GetValue(r)).ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }

    // ***
    // *** MemberInfo Extensions
    // ***
    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    // ***
    // *** Type Extensions
    // ***
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();
}
```